# How to get date string from Date() in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Javascript provide a method to get current date called [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it will print an object like: `Tue Aug 24 2021 04:18:08 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)` , but i want to get the current date format , like an string or array like `"24 08 2021"` or `Array(3){"24","08","2021"}`

How can i do that? Thank you guy a a lots

Link to that method [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Take a look at moment.js format method. will make your life a lot easier. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Example for you

```js
var today = new Date();
let dateString = `${today.getDate()} ${today.getMonth()} ${today.getFullYear()}`;
let dateArray = [
    today.getDate().toString(),
    today.getMonth().toString(),
    today.getFullYear().toString()
];
console.log(dateString);
console.log(dateArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

For format dd mm yyyy:

```js
var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join(' ');
console.log(today);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can look at here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString
There are a lot of functions that helps you deal with dates in Javascript.

Happy coding! :)